# How to restrict copy paste browser url of pop up window in php

Tags: javascript, php

My Pop up window function is like that:

```
 function PopWin111(url){
    openwin111=this.open(url,"CtrlWindow","_blank","fullscreen=yes, status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,addressbar=no");
    openwin111.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: and what is wrong with it? Please elaborate on your questio, we need to know what the expected behaviour is, and the actual behaviour so we can identify the problem

Comment: He wants to know if there is a way to retrict copy and paste browser url. And no there isn't. But there is a way to hhide the url bar in the new window.

Comment: the browser pop up window url should not be copyor drag n drop  in another window of browser

Comment: how to hide the url bar in pop up window??

Comment: Why do you want to restrict it? If you can't copy it in the popup window itself, you can still find it in the code that opens the window.

Comment: Refer the documentation : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp